# What will happen if I concatenate one-hot-encoded class along with features?

Tags: neural-networks

Here is one row from my data:

```
H  7.042 5.781 5.399  -9.118   5.488  7.470
```

The first column is the class. The rest of them are features.

I encoded the classes using one-hot-encoding, concatenated them with the feature list:

```
    1   0  1  7.042 5.781 5.399  -9.118   5.488  7.470
```

Then I used this list for training.

1. Is this a valid technique?
2. Am I achieving anything really useful here?

- Cross posted in [ai.SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/34639/what-will-happen-if-i-concatenate-one-hot-encoded-categorical-features-along-wit)

Comment: is it the class you want to predict?

Comment: @gunes, yes, that is correct.

Comment: There must be some missing context or assumptions. On its face, this procedure is using the class labels to predict the class labels, which is entirely tautological -- any machine learning method worthy of the name should easily achieve it. What problem are you trying to solve and how does this proposed method help you solve it?

Comment: @Sycorax, My supervisor says that I made a mistake by using labels as features. I am trying to understand what I did wrong. In my view, the mistake seems to be: when I am using labels as features, I must provide those labels as input whenever I want to use the trained model. Therefore, this trained model is practically useless. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, your advisor is correct. If you already know the answer (the labels) then why are you building a model? The reason to build a model is that you have the features and want to use them to predict the label. If you have the labels, then you'd just use the labels as-is and skip building and using a model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In comments, OP clarifies that the model is predicting the class labels and also is using the class labels as features. This is entirely tautological. If we have the label information, then there's no reason to build a model at all -- just use the label to achieve whatever task that needs to know the label.

If your model uses the label as a feature, then you also won't be able to use the model to make predictions, except in cases when you **already** have the label information. So in this sense, the model exhibits *circular logic*.

In the specific case of the data in OP's question, we could paraphrase the machine learning task as "The label is `H`. Can you predict the label?" We don't need to do any work at all to answer this question, because you told us that the label is `H`.

In the usual setting, the reason to build a model is that the class label information is not available when we would like.

- If we want to know the price of a share of stock 6 months in the future, we will either have to wait 6 months, make an educated guess, or use a model to make a prediction.
- If we want to read the addresses on all pieces of mail, either we pay hundreds of humans to read those addresses and route the mail accordingly, or we can use a model to read pictures of the address labels.

So when you ask "Is this a valid technique?" and "Am I achieving anything really useful?" the answer to both is **NO**.

The bounty asks for a authoritative reference. I'm not aware of one that explicitly addresses this. But I think Hastie et al.'s [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/) makes it clear that the purpose of the supervised model is to estimate some quantity *that we don't already know*.

> Statistical learning plays a key role in many areas of science, finance and
> industry. Here are some examples of learning problems:
>
> - Predict whether a patient, hospitalized due to a heart attack, will have a second heart attack. The prediction is to be based on demographic, diet and clinical measurements for that patient.
> - Predict the price of a stock in 6 months from now, on the basis of company performance measures and economic data.
> - Identify the numbers in a handwritten ZIP code, from a digitized
>   image.

Answer (score 6):

If you include the target in your features, the neural network will use that feature. It's no use unless you're conducting a very specific experiment with neural networks to see if they'll be able to pick it up; which I doubt any would miss.